# Forecasting with unscaled data using coefficient estimates from a penalized regression on scaled data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, lasso, vector-autoregression, feature-scaling

This is an embarrassingly basic question, but I keep producing absurd estimates from a pretty well-fitting model, so I think I’m making some fundamental mistake. I have a longish time series that I am using to calibrate a short horizon (6 period) model, i.e. each predicted value is based only on the preceding six periods. My model is a vector autoregression with LASSO penalties on a first difference in logs, with the shrinkage parameter estimated by leave-one-out cross-validation. I also have some vector error correction models, and some models in logs for comparason. All variables, both left- and right-hand side, are continuous and are scaled (converted to Z-scores).

For compelling confidentiality reasons I will not go into, I need to calculate my predicted values on the unscaled data, for both dependent and independent variables. So I think I should multiply my estimated coefficient of each variable by its variance, and then set the constant to the sum of the unscaled training data left-hand means. And I think I should use the training data only for varience and mean estimates. Is that correct? Should I be multiplying the means by my scaled or unscaled coefficients? Do I have the sign right? If I knew that this part of my estimationwas correct, it would help me to focus my attention where the problem really is.

Comment: I would definitely expect absurd estimates from any model that is fitted on only 6 data points, let alone a model as rich in parameters as a VAR or a VECM.

Comment: Richard, the models I am fitting have a maximum lag of six periods (because longer lags were insignificant), but I am fitting the model over about 2000 periods of data.